# Stacking two different stratified tables

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to combine to different stratified tables made with `tbl_strata()`and `tbl_summary` from the `gtsummary`-package. I want to stratify by the same variable in both tables, but use different variables in the "by" argument in `tbl_summary()`. When I combine the tables using `tbl_stack()`, the column headers from the second table are lost. Is there any way to combine the tables and keep the column headers from both tables?

See reproducible example below

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
data("diamonds")

table1 <- diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Ideal", "Premium") & color %in% c("E", "I")) %>%
  mutate(color = factor(color)) %>% 
  tbl_strata(strata = cut, 
             .tbl_fun = 
               ~.x %>% 
               tbl_summary(by = color, include = price))

table2 <- diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Ideal", "Premium") & clarity %in% c("SI1", "SI2")) %>%
  mutate(clarity = factor(clarity)) %>% 
  tbl_strata(strata = cut, 
             .tbl_fun = 
               ~.x %>% 
               tbl_summary(by = clarity, include = price))

tbl_stack(list(table1, table2), group_header = c("Table 1", "Table 2"))
```

UPDATE:

Below is an (rough) example of the output I would like to be able to get from `tbl_stack()`:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

data("diamonds")

library(flextable)

table1_tibble <- diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Ideal", "Premium") & color %in% c("E", "I")) %>%
  mutate(color = factor(color)) %>% 
  tbl_strata(strata = cut, 
             .tbl_fun = 
               ~.x %>% 
               tbl_summary(by = color, include = price)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

table1_tibble <- rbind(colnames(table1_tibble), table1_tibble) %>% 
  rename(label = colnames(table1_tibble)[1], 
         premium_1 = colnames(table1_tibble)[2], 
         premium_2 = colnames(table1_tibble)[3], 
         ideal_1 = colnames(table1_tibble)[4], 
         ideal_2 = colnames(table1_tibble)[5]) %>% 
  add_row(label = "Table 1", .before = 1)

table2_tibble <- diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Ideal", "Premium") & clarity %in% c("SI1", "SI2")) %>%
  mutate(clarity = factor(clarity)) %>% 
  tbl_strata(strata = cut, 
             .tbl_fun = 
               ~.x %>% 
               tbl_summary(by = clarity, include = price)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

table2_tibble <- rbind(colnames(table2_tibble), table2_tibble) %>% 
  rename(label = colnames(table2_tibble)[1], 
         premium_1 = colnames(table2_tibble)[2], 
         premium_2 = colnames(table2_tibble)[3], 
         ideal_1 = colnames(table2_tibble)[4], 
         ideal_2 = colnames(table2_tibble)[5]) %>% 
  add_row(label = "Table 2", .before = 1)


bind_rows(table1_tibble, table2_tibble) %>% 
  flextable() %>%
  merge_at(i = 1, j = 2:3, part = "header") %>% 
  merge_at(i = 1, j = 4:5, part = "header") %>% 
  set_header_labels(label = "", premium_1 = "Premium", ideal_1 = "Ideal")
```

Hope this clarifies matters.

Best regards,

Martin

Comment: There can only be one set of headers in a single table.  Can update your post with an example of what you'd like to see?

Comment: Hi @DanielD.Sjoberg I've updated the question now, hopefully this explains what I am trying to accomplish.